# Export LaTeX to HTML for simple documentaiton

Tags: html, documentation, latex2html

how is the best option or program to export `LaTeX` to `HTML` and upload to the web?

I tried `LaTeXtoHTML` but I am not convinced.

Now I am using `TeXmaker` for my documentation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not convinced'?  Keep in mind that things like readthedocs.org are *not* just HTML.

Comment: Sorry @SeanAllred I don't know about readthedocs.org I will take a look. I'm newbie and I don't know how to publish on-line documentation :( Can you orientate me with any link or first steps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on your documents, but usually people use tex4ht to convert LaTeX to HTML. I'm often obliged to offer a html-version of my documents, but on the other hand writing LaTeX is so much easier than using "Word", so I offer a beautiful PDF and an HTML file. One can do this on the base of the same document, but some packages are not well supported by tex4ht, so I use this code to replace them (e.g. libertine against lmodern) for the HTML file:

```
\makeatletter
\newif\ifhtlatex
\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{%
  \htlatextrue% Wenn mit tex4ht kompiliert wird
  \usepackage{lmodern}
}{%
  \htlatexfalse% Es wird ein PDF erstellt
  \usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
  \usepackage[osf]{libertine}
  \SetTracking{encoding= * , shape = sc}{25}
}
\makeatother
```

---

*Edit:*

I try to avoid the necessity for improvement of the html output. It is more efficient to improve the process of transfer from LaTeX to HTML.

Example: I often use the scrjura package. Some really nice persons on the tex4ht mailing list wrote "scrjura.cfg", which transfers my layout correctly to html. The command now ist `htlatex <filename> "scrjura" " -cunihtf"` (there is a space between the " and the - in the sectond option!).

As a result, I get correct output. Usually...

If you are going to transfer more than one file occasionally from LaTeX to HTML, I suggest to ask on the tex4ht mailing list or here about a *.cfg file for a package you need.

Comment: Thank you very much!
What do you do in the second hand after convert to HTML? Do you only edit CSS or also HTML for make it better?

Comment: There is also a user here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2891/michal-h21 , who is an expert, see this website he maintains: https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ebook

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand all. :( The package 'scrjura' helps to do better HTML but do you not recommend?

Comment: @Neil I recommend to avoid digging in the HTML or CSS output after conversion manually and I think it is better to solve issues by using config files during conversion.

Comment: Thanks I understand. And sorry for all questions. The last one: What those that config files? Are there any link for read more? Thanks and sorry for all that stuff.